# After update setfocus not working Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the amount field, which will give a message if the amount becomes too much after giving input, it is still working. But the amount is not right, it has become too much, it is giving the message that the amount is not focusing again in the field. Please help.

```
Private Sub Amount_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(Me.[InvoiceRef].Column(3)) And Not IsNull(Me.Amount) Then
        If CInt(Me.[Amount]) > CInt(Me.[InvoiceRef].Column(3)) Then
            MsgBox "You have given input in excess of the amount due.", vbExclamation, "Receipt Amount"
            Me.Amount.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use the `Exit` event.

Comment: While it may not seem obvious, any data validation checks should be handled in [BeforeUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.beforeupdate-event) event to warn user entry.